# Need to copy images from diff folder in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have 500 folders of templates in one folder. Now  each folder has file called template_thumbnail.png . now i want something so that all those files get copied to one folder with name same as the home folder name

is it possible

I have cygwin installed and i can copy that folder in there so basically it will linux shell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for DIR in *; { if [ -d "${DIR}" ]; then cp "${DIR}/template_thumbnail.png" "${DIR}.png"; fi; }
```

That takes each entry in the current directory and checks it's a directory.  If it is it copies the dirname/template_thumbnail.png to dirname.png.

Comment: Note he said "copied" not "moved", so "cp" would be better than "mv".

Comment: Oops - my bad - edited

Comment: is it possible that it also searches for file in sub folders as well , because some of my png files are in further subfolders

Comment: Now you're getting more complex...  You'll have to do some trickery with the `find` command for that.